# Pharo on Ubuntu 13.04 : error with not finding module "vm-display-X11"

Tags: ubuntu, 32bit-64bit, smalltalk, pharo

I have downloaded Pharo 2.0 installer for Linux.  On Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit, I have `ia32-libs` and `ia32-libs-multiarch` installed already.  However, when I launch Pharo, I get an error: `could not find module vm-display-X11`.  After that, it aborts.

The said file is available in the `bin` directory, as usual.  I had never run into this error earlier.  I recently re-installed Ubuntu, after which I am having this error.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

vm-display-X11 probably has some unmet dependencies, use ldd to find them

```
ldd pharo-vm/vm-display-X11
```

This should output something similar to

```
linux-gate.so.1 (0xf776e000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7706000)
libGL.so.1 => not found
libX11.so.6 => not found
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf7539000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf776f000)
```

In ubuntu use dpkg -S to find the packages that provide those dependencies

```
dpkg -S libGL.so.1 libX11.so.6
```

And finally install them with your package manager

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to install Pharo on Ubuntu is to use the dedicated PPA:

See the "Ubuntu ppa" section at [**http://pharo.org/download**](http://pharo.org/download)

Answer (score 3):

From pharo.org: [http://pharo.org/gnu-linux-installation#debian8](http://pharo.org)

The installation in more recent Ubuntu & Debian distributions requires some operations.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install libx11-6:i386 
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1:i386 
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0:i386
```

It should works

Answer (score 2):

The following two steps solved the problem.

1. `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib32/libGL.so.1`
2. `sudo ldconfig`

Not pretty, but it worked!

Comment: Sounds like it might be worth passing to the Ubuntu libGL maintainer as a bug report.